# Add page number in page title - magento

Tags: magento

Have one issue which don't like google for seo.
All the categories having the same title if going by pages in that category, so I want to add page number in page title. Is any solution?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you think Google will accept this technique which is controlling everything of page!

Comment: Yes, because I'm now getting many errors, because so many pages with the same title.

Answer (score 1):

Copy file from `/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php` modify with the following code which is getting default page number.

```
Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getCurrentPage();
```

Comment: Rather than use the include path to override the head block, use Magento's class rewriting mechanism to implement your own class which extends from the original and rewrite only the methods which you need to.